# Setting up an Orchard project from scratch to work in a TEAM and with different environment settings

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I need to create a new Orchard Project to work **in a team** and I find myself lost. My main questions now are:

1. How to have three **different SQL connection strings** depending on the deployment environment (local, development, production)
2. Once we will have content-definitions and content we are happy with in local, How do we migrate it to development or production? How do you **control version the database**?
3. Is this a **good path**?: We are willing to work with VisualStudio instead of WebMatrix because eventually we will have to create our own modules and all the tutorials from Lombiq use VS. 
   I have created a branch named Orchard.SourceCode containing the
   1.9.1-v source code and a Development branch. Every time Orchard has a new release I will replace files in Orchard.SourceCode with the new release code, commit and merge to Development.

I have already googled but if you find some really useful link I may have missed, don't hesitate to share.

Note: We are using Mercurial as CVS

Comment: Apart from the points that you already got answers to, I recommend creating a separate `*.sln` file with just the most necessary modules and cspoj's, and replace module dependencies with library dependencies. This speed-up your work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should have on each machine (local,production,development1,development2) its own files within those folders Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites, Orchard.Web\App_Data\RecipeQueue, Orchard.Web\App_Data\Logs, src\Orchard.Web\Media\ so those folder shouldn't be in the repository. Because as @NetWave explained the connection string and other local data are there.
2. The recommendation is that while you can you should use Import-Export feature for importing-exporting recipes. The alternate option is to use the migrations mechanism [Orchard Data Access Layer](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-data-access). The point is if you don't need to add or alter tables in db for your custom parts you should use recipes. In our case we have one module with one recipe called upgrade-recipe.xml. There we add all the new things to add to the next upgrade. When the upgrade is performed we clean that file. It helps us to maintain our migrations files small. In fact for operations like remove a content item or all the content items of a type we have created commands which can be also executed from a recipe.
3. For me it is ok that configuration. I like to have the code in a repository because sometimes I fix Orchard bugs and I can't wait they accept my pull request. Maybe you can improve it having the source of Orchard as a fork of the original repository. It will make easier to you send pull requests to them.

Comment: Just one question: Why do you put the upgrade-recipe.xml **inside a module**? Would it be enough if we had an "upgrades" folder containing the files we create to upgrade? We would do it by naming the files something like
 
2015_08_28_15hh17mm/00_Add_GoogleMaps_Widget.xml
2015_08_28_15hh17mm/01_Enable_Localization_Feature.xml
...

Comment: It is good question. The reason is I want to have the recipe available to execute it automatically from migrations. So, I add code to the migrations of that module to execute it when there is something to update. This is the code I add to  the migrations file of the module:
_recipeManager.TryExecute(_recipeHarvester.HarvestRecipes("PCCom.Plantilla").First(x => x.Name == "Plantilla Update"));

Comment: But be careful, to launch recipes from migrations is a feature broken at 1.9.1. The fix has been merged in 1.9.x  https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/5571 so it will be solved in 1.9.2 that is expected to be released soon

Answer (score 1):

What I always do is this:

1. Orchard Source code using Visual Studio for developing my own modules in local.
2. An Azure Orchard web site for my test environment.
3. The definitions of the Content Types can be exported from your test environment to production using Export / Import module. Or you can create your own Content Types definitions through the Migration file in your own module.

I wouldn't include the whole solution of the source code of Orchard in your source control, instead just include the module you are developing. Once Orchard is updated to a new version, create a new environment.

I hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The connection string can be found in App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt.

We always use the full source code of Orchard to develop a new site in Visual Studio. Unlike Ramon, we store the complete solution in TFS. So each site has a seperate copy of the full source code. Some are 1.8.x, some 1.9.x, etc... Storage is cheap, right? ;)

Having a source and a dev branch is something I've also done in the past. It's easy to apply source changes to your dev branch. I've done this for the 1.9 branch when it was still in development (1.x) but I wanted to use the new layout features. But most of the time, a stable version of Orchard is picked when we start a new site (1.9.1 for example) and the source is hardly updated (only small bugfixes).

Concerning the database... The first time a site is put into preprod, we just copy the entire database. After that, migrations is the most common way to keep types in sync. Import/export can be used to keep the data in sync (but this is something we hardly use).

I hope this helps.